# Windows 7 machine not setting homepage via GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer, homepage

A Windows 7 machine that is currently deployed has its homepage currently set as:
http://hp-comm.us.msn.com/?pc=CMDTDF&OCID=HPDHP

We have a GPO in place that sets all authenticated users IE homepage to an internal Intranet site. This machine is not accepting this and is not allowing up to set a homepage on our own.

Windows 7
IE 9
Server is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Is this machine new to your domain? Are other group policies being applied? Is the GPO in question linked to the root of the domain, or to an OU?

Comment: Is this the first Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Do you see the policy being applied in the `gpresult /z` output?

Comment: While MOST Group Policy will work on Windows 7, there are some new things that 2003 will not be able to manage. This article is for Vista, but the principles are the same. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766208(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this a new machine that has been joined to your domain very recently, it is possible that the computer may not be in the correct Organizational Unit to receive the policy in question.

In Active Directory Users and Computers, please check to see whether this machine's Computer object is still in the default Computers container. If it is, please move the Computer object to the correct Organizational Unit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you update the group policy ? ( gpupdate /force )
2. Does the machine allow you to set it manually ?
3. Is this an isolated issue ( only on one machine ) or is it a Domain wide problem ?
4. Does the machine reach the DC, and does the GPO get applied on the machine ? ( gpresult )